# Contact Form - only issue: PHP is not returning INPUTs

Tags: php, html, forms, email, input

I have been working with this for a couple days and have read thru MANY previously posed questions, as well as several tutorial sites... The Contact Form submits, confirms and redirects... It sends the email, with headers and subject line, to correct address... just NO inputs... no "FROM SENDER EMAIL", no FROM NAME INPUT, no EMAIL INPUT, no MESSAGE INPUT... HELP! So close, and yet so far... any advice is greatly appreciated ~ I write HTML & CSS, novice at JS and practically NO PHP experience... Thank You in Advance! :)

Here's the HTML contact-form:

```
 <form action= "contact-form.php" id="contact-form" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label><input name="cf-name" type="text" value="Your     Name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your     Name' ) this.value=''" /></label>
                                <label>
                                <input name="cf-email" type="text" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''" />
                                </label>
                        <textarea name="cf-message" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Message'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Message' ) this.value=''">Message</textarea>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <p><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').reset()">Clear</a>
                                      <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()">Send</a></p>
                                    <p>&nbsp;
                                        </p>
                                </div>                                          
                          </fieldset>           
                        </form>
```

and here is the PHP (contact-form.php):

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'info@anelectrician.net';
$subject = 'Message from a website visitor...'.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From:'.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail:'.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message:'.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for your correspondence. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@anelectrician.net');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: *sidenote*, you need to validate your user inputs, check there set before using and check cf_email is actually an email; also you have no protection from email header injection, which will result in your server sending spam

Comment: Thank You Loz... will do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a difference here... In PHP you are using underscores and in HTML you are using dashes.

You can always test what is going wrong and where your code is by debugging with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

That should help you figure out if you are just not using the correct keys.

Comment: Thank You smc (and all!)... yeah, um, feeling quite ridiculous now... lol... I do appreciate the tips! Thanks again! >.<

Answer (score 1):

Change these

```
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
```

to these

```
$field_name = $_POST['cf-name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf-email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf-message'];
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer to the ridiculous question.

Answer (score 0):

The items in your $_POST need to match the name attributes of the inputs. Your inputs have dashes, but your $_POST references have underscores. For example:

`<input name="cf-name" ... >` should be `<input name="cf_name" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

Your html inputs have dashes while your PHP name inputs have underscores